# WordPress update post meta data (custom field) by post link

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have a post in my wordpress website, which has lot of custom fields.
I also have an excel sheet with "post link" - "custom field data" combination.
That custom field(video url) is already set for each post, But now i need to change and update those links appropriate to excel sheet. I do not have a 
"post_id - post metadata" combination, just link and appropriate metadata value.

Is there a way to update these data with some plugin or code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write and execute a [WP command](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Commands-Cookbook).
Save your spreadsheet as CSV file and use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) to iterate through it. For each entry find a post using [url_to_postid()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) and update the metadata as needed.

Comment: Thanks for help, I have already done it. My main problem was the FTP account i had was with private permisions, so i couldn't use fgetcsv, so i used the different server, converted csv to db in that server, then the i got the sql query for inserting csv data to table, converted url to ids, then updated meta data, it was a bit longer, but that is what i had. :)